# python UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```py
count = 0

def checkletters(string):
    for letter in string:
        count +=1
input = input("What string do you want me to check for letter count: ")
checkletters(input)
print(f"There are {count} letters in that string")
```

I want the script to ask the user to input a string and it will send the amount of letters in the string

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `len()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to resolve this issue i have two for you

**1. make you `count` variable `global`**

> `global count`
>
> ```
>     count = 0
>     def checkletters(string):
>         for letter in string:
>             global count
>             count +=1
>     input = input("What string do you want me to check for letter count: ")
>     checkletters(input)
>
>     print(f"There are {count} letters in that string")
> ```

---

**2. By using `count` variable inside the function and returning value from that func..**

> ```
> def checkletters(string):
>     count = 0
>     for letter in string:
>        count +=1
>     return count 
> input = input("What string do you want me to check for letter count: ")
> checkletters(input)
> print(f"There are {checkletters(input)} letters in that string")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way:

```
def checkletters(string):
    count = 0
    for letter in string:
        count +=1
    return count
input = input("What string do you want me to check for letter count: ")
count = checkletters(input)
print(f"There are {count} letters in that string")
```